# Entry price to consider while doing a forward/backtest test?

Tags: backtesting

1 min timeframe signal generation.

Thing I have considered:

1 - `Close` price can be predictive in nature

Counter: shifted the `entry` price to the open of next minute.

2- Added stop-loss.

3- Brokerage/other charges

I did in-sample fitting and then out-sample test. Both the results are very good.

The strategy is now live and I am facing certain issues.

The entry price almost never matches, I assume this is because of the `seconds` gap between order generation and placement.

I realise that this will happen and I can't change much about it at this time. I am trying to understand:

What Entry price should I consider in the backtest and forward test(after market I run the strategy on closed data)?

I am thinking of this:

`(high + low)/2`

Is there a universally accepted/recommended approach?

TIA

Comment: There are a few issues to consider. First of all trading at an open price based on the close price of the previous minute is clearly unrealistic for almost all purposes, as the prices are recorded at virtually the same moment. Using the next minute's close could be realistic. Then there are bid-ask spreads. So you could not necessarily buy even at next minute's close, if that's someone crossing the spread to sell. 

So I'd say the prudent approach would be to buy at next minute's closing ask and sell at next minute's closing bid.

Comment: If bid-ask data is not available, then I would just use the next minutes' closing price and add to it half of the average bid-ask spread when buying, and subtract when selling. If this approach makes the strategy unprofitable in a backtest, then it almost certainly will be so in live.

Comment: @MGL thanks. I am trying to wrap my head around using the close price as the entry while the order will be placed within 10-20 seconds of the the minute?

Comment: Using the close price as I described above, is a way to make sure you use a price that is in all likelihood achievable. Actually this is the first price that satisfies the condition. Clearly the open price comes too early, as using that would imply instantaneous execution. In my opinion, there's really no reason for using (high+low)/2 either, nor can it be guaranteed to be achievable. If the next close price is too much of a lag for your strategy, then you would just need to get a higher frequency dataset for testing, or accept that the live performance can be way different than the backtest.